# Tag wiki suggested edit reviews

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I know that we don't have that many users with high rep. yet, but I'm just wondering how the review for suggested edits work? As per [@GeneJ](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/402)'s suggestion, I improved the suggested edit for the numbering tag wiki and excerpt. Is @GeneJ able to change her review vote or is it waiting now for someone else to pipe in and vote?

It's been awhile, so just wondering if it is due to the suggested edit being poor, or because there are only a few reviewers available?

ps - if you think my suggested edits are half on and half off, you could approve the edits and then submit your own edit to spruce up the parts that you think could be improved.

Comment: I believe the problem is that I "skipped" the vote (being ultra-cautious on wording I did not like much but was not certain was wrong). Now, if there is a review task on the item, it is not being shown to me.

Comment: @Fortiter I just edited it again, so it should be in the review section again in its new form :)

Comment: I normally see Reviews but I haven't seen one for several weeks now

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear I can change a vote (nor do I have tag edit privileges).

Update: Yes! TYTY. If you navigate to the tag (in the tag-wiki), then select "edit pending" you CAN revote on the tag information. (Don't know if this option only appears if an edit has been made since your last vote.)

Comment: Hi, sorry. Took out the word 'direct' ancestors, but you were really looking for the word 'descendants' to be put in. Changed it again. Check it out :) ...it is a wiki, so it should be updated and improved upon over time.